# how to split string from the end after certain occurances of character

Tags: python

how to split the below string after 2nd occurrence of '/' from the end:

```
/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_home
```

Expected output is :

```
/u01/dbms/orcl/product/
```

Thanks.

Comment: An easier method might be to parse the path with a path library (such as `pathlib`) if that's an option

Comment: `'/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_home'.rsplit('/', 2)[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `split`, use `rsplit` instead! It's much simpler and faster.

```
s = '/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_home'
result = s.rsplit('/', 2)[0] + '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_home"
split_string = string.split('/')
expected_output = "/".join(split_string[:-2]) + "/"
```

You're also free to change "-2" to minus whatever amount of filenames you need clipped.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 true, mb, fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you can parse it as a filepath, I recommend `pathlib`, try:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_hom')

p.parent.parent # Returns object containg path /u01/dbms/orc1/product/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input='/u01/dbms/orcl/product/11.2.0.4/db_home'
output = '/'.join(str(word) for word in input.split('/')[:-2])+'/'
```